# Convert Vector<String> to CStrings

Tags: string, rust

I want to pick an argument given to my program, convert it to `CString` and pass it as zero-terminated `const char*` to a C function.

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let arg1 = args[1];
let arg1copy = CString::new(&arg1).unwrap();
external_c_func(arg1copy.as_ptr());
```

But I get "the trait From<&String> is not implemented for String". It does work if I replace `args[1]` with a constant String "like this".

How do I do it properly? It's tiresome that simple stuff like this requires so much investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what we have here:

- `CString::new` is implemented for every data structure that implements `Into<Vec<u8>>` (i.e. can be turned into a `Vec<u8>` without copying the contents of the buffer);
- `String` implements `Into<Vec<u8>>`;
- but here, what you have is not `String` but `&String` - you can create a `Vec<u8>` from it, but this will take a buffer copy, so it doesn't implement `Into<Vec>;
- the reason you have an `&String` is that you're manipulating a pointer to an item within an array, not the item itself.

There are many ways out of it.

## Just copy the String

To obtain a `String` from a `&String`, call `.clone()`. This will copy the contents of the string in memory.

```rust
let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
let arg_1 = &args[1];
let arg_1_copy = CString::new(arg_1.clone()).unwrap();

external_c_func(arg_1_copy.as_ptr());
```

## Don't put it in a vector in the first place

```rust
let mut args = std::env::args();
let arg_1 = args.next().unwrap();
let arg_1_copy = CString::new(arg1).unwrap();

external_c_func(arg_1_copy.as_ptr());
```

## Remove it from the vector

```rust
let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
let arg_1 = args.remove(0);
let arg_1_copy = CString::new(arg_1).unwrap();

external_c_func(arg_1_copy.as_ptr());
```

## Build a vector of CStrings instead

```rust
let conversions: Result<Vec<CString>, _> = std::env::args().map(CString::new).collect();
let args = conversions.unwrap();
external_c_func(args[0].as_ptr());
```

etc.